# Eclemma: branches missed in a for-loop -- what does it mean?

Tags: java, for-loop, code-coverage, eclemma

Testing my code I've encountered a thing that I can't interpret. Examining the code coverage with `eclemma` I've found a header of a `for-loop` that is highlighted in yellow with the message reading `"1 of 2 branches missing"`.

The code line is as following:

```
    for (int i = maxIdx; i >= 0; i--) {
```

The body of the loop is highlighted as covered (and is actually executed), as well as the preceding and following statements, and the method works fine under all possible conditions. The headers of other `for-loops`, as far as I could notice, are highlighted in yellow with the same message only in cases if the body of the loop have never executed.

What is the sense of this message? What branch is missing?

Comment: What `maxIdx` do you use in your tests?

Comment: @Mureinik It's the index of the last char in a `StringBuilder`: `maxIdx = sb.length() - 1`, typically 30 or 40. This expression was initially in the loop header, but trying to understand what's the matter with it, I've moved it in a separate line. Yet it has not changed the behavior of `eclemma`.

Comment: What happens if you create a test with maxIdx set to -1, shouldn't that cover the other branch?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the headers remains yellow, the body becomes red, as expected.

Comment: Why would the body become red? I wanted you to create one more test, not edit the  existing one. So one test where the for loop is entered and one where it is not.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, you're right. Running this code with an empty `StringBuilder` paints it green. But strange -- why then other loops that always executed at least once are green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how `for` loop of the form

```
for (ForInit; ForCondition; ForUpdate)
  Body
```

is executed:

1. `ForInit` is executed
2. `ForCondition` is evaluated

   - when `false`, then `Body` is not executed and execution continues after loop
   - when `true`, then `Body` is executed, `ForUpdate` is executed and execution continues from step 2

"2 branches" correspond to the above two options for `ForCondition`.

"1 of 2 branches missing" means that happened only one of these options, either first one, or second one.

---

In absence of **[complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** that includes body of your loop, hard to answer your additional questions

> But strange -- why then other loops that always executed at least once are green?
>
> Yet it's rather strange -- why other loops are always green?

However given that `Body` of your loop was executed, possible that there is exit from the loop in the `Body` before `ForCondition` evaluates to `false`.

For example using latest as of today version 2018-12 of Eclipse IDE for Java that comes with EclEmma 3.1.1:

[image: example]

And maybe there is no such exits in your other loops:

[image: example]

This can also explain

> Running this code with an empty `StringBuilder` paints it green.

and

> Adding an artificially created situation with an empty `StringBuilder` (that's impossible in reality) colors the loop in green.

because of added case when `ForCondition` evaluates to `false` before execution of `Body`:

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you! You are right, there is a conditional exit (`break`) from the  loop body in my code, I did not think about it. I's a carry propagation in a long number represented as a string, from less significant digits toward higher digits, if the next digit in turn is '9' it is replaced with '0' and the propagation goes on, otherwise the digit is incremented and the loop is exited. The situation is quite clear for me now, and I see that my initial test data did not cover all possible cases. Now I've added necessary data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the missing branches refer to the condition `i >= 0`. Since `i` is initialized with a positive `maxIdx` (according to the comments), you should probably also add test cases for `maxIdx` of `0` and a negative `maxIdx`.

Note that since `maxIdx` is the length of a `StringBuilder` (according to the comments), this may not be possible, and you'd have to either live with the missing branch, or "artificially" refactor your code so that you can pass a negative `maxIdx`.

Comment: Other similar loops are colored green even though the body is executed in all cases, like `(for int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Adding an artificially created situation with an empty `StringBuilder` (that's impossible in reality) colors the loop in green. Yet it's rather strange -- why other loops are always green?

Comment: @m.vokhm I think the difference is that in the example in the OP `maxIdx` is a variable, and you can control how its initialized, so eclemma expects you to cover all the options. In the other example you gave here in the comments, `i` is initialized with a hard corded value and also compared to a hardcoded value.

Comment: @Mureinik for EclEmma there is absolutely no difference between `i = maxIdx` and `i = 0`.